# Failure to run commands from apache karaf client

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have downloaded apache karaf2.3.3 (on felix) on several CentOS6.4 machines. I see this issue only in a few machines. When I try to install a feature using the following commands

```
$KARAF_HOME/bin/start
$KARAF_HOME/bin/client "features:install myfeature"
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
WARN org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSessionImpl - Exception caught
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:273)
at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:44)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:690)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:664)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:653)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1124)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Looks like client fails to connect to karaf. Firewall is shutdown on all of the machines. Anyone knows why this could be failing? The feature gets happily installed if run karaf in console mode with /bin/karaf and type in the same command

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the port you defined for the remote Karaf console was already in use by another application before the Karaf installation. As such the wrong application accepts the link, cannot make anything of the data and resets the connection. I would suggest to stop Karaf, check with `netstat` or via `telnet localhost <port>` whether the port Karaf is configured to listen on is already in use, and find the related application. As an alternative, you can configure Karaf to use a different (not used) port. See for example [this page](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/remote-console.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am using the default karaf setting which is 8101 for ssh port. No process other than karaf is using that port. A tcpdump shows ./bin/client tries to push packets into the karaf server, and the server responds with an RST, this destroying the connection. Karaf itself crashes after sending this RST. I still don't know what's going on, and it's bordering on becoming a christmas miracle :-(